# Requiring files to mocha test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

My test module looks something like this

```
//require('./main');
//require('../main');
//require('./scripts/main');
//require('./src/scripts/main');
//require('./src/scripts/main');
//require('../scripts/main');
//require('../src/scripts/main');

var
  assert = require('chai').assert,
  //Notices = require('../src/scripts/notices/notices'),
  notices = new Notices();

describe('NoticesTest', function() {

  describe('getImportantNotices', function () {

    it('Should return array of ImportanceNotice', function () {
      /*notices.getImportantNotices().then(function(val) {
        console.log(val);
        assert.equal(val.data.length, 50);
      }).catch(function() {
        assert.equal(true, false);
      });*/

    });

  });

});
```

In the module I do

```
export default Notices;
```

And I try to require javascript files into it but it fails (Cannot find module). I'm using babel to write ES6 and the `require` is ES6 require not requirejs. May it be that ES6 require does not work in mocha and it needs requirejs to require my modules?

Comment: Also `require('chai').assert;` is valid and works but my .js files still not found.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use

```
import Notices from '<path>';
```

Comment: Yes I've tried, this also fails. Import gives `Unexpected reserved word`

Comment: It looks like something wrong with your Babel configuration. Are you using Babel 5 or 6? Have you added presets "es2015" and "stage-0"?

Comment: Right, I'm using babelify for that. Will check it later in the evening and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I was missing .babelrc file with "es2015" in it